# Xcode/clang no longer compiling C++14 code after updating Xcode: "no member named make_shared"

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I am no longer able to build my C++ project after coming back to it after a while (I've since updated macOS and Xcode), either from Xcode or by calling clang on the command line. I am getting an error on every use of std::shared_ptr::make_shared in my code. I want to emphasize *this used to compile* and run fine and I don't understand what has changed. Perhaps updating xcode broke my toolchain somehow.

I have reproduced the problem in some very trivial code that I believe should compile fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class test_c {
    private:
        std::string str_;
    
    public:
        test_c(std::string str__) : str_(str__) { }
};

std::string test_s = "test";
auto test = std::shared_ptr<test_c>::make_shared(test_s);
```

The errors look like this:

```
$ clang -std=c++14 test.cpp
test.cpp:10:38: error: no member named 'make_shared' in 'std::__1::shared_ptr<test_c>'
auto test = std::shared_ptr<test_c>::make_shared(test_s);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: AFAIK, `std::shared_ptr` has never had a static member function named `make_shared`.  `auto test = std::make_shared(test_s);` should compile for you.

Comment: What compiler/version/build settings were you using when this code compiled successfully?

Comment: You can't compile with private constructor :D

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe it was an older Xcode, 10.3 I think. I remember I had changed a build setting to specifically use a C++14 dialect, but none of the options seem to work anymore. I can't even build on the command line.

Comment: @NathanOliver The docs seem to agree with you (not sure how I had this compiling before) but now I'm getting "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument"…

Comment: @devios1 See the answer below for the correct syntax.  I forgot to specify the type to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any way to call `make_shared` as a static method at all. Also checked your code in other in older versions of Clang. Doesn't seem that it can work...

Maybe just:

```cpp
auto test = std::make_shared<test_c>(test_s);
```

**UPD**
Wait. Indeed it worked in in [clang of version 9](https://godbolt.org/z/WbsqEn). Looks it really was updated to disable this feature...
Not working in [v10](https://godbolt.org/z/6EYKf8).